# Getting an error wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on UbuntuShared

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 as guest OS in Virtual box and my base OS is widnows8.1 Pro. I am relatively new to Ubuntu OS

When I am trying to share the files between Host OS to guest OS I did the following things

1. I have installed Guest additions
2. After that I set the Shared folders and the given name as "Ubuntu-shared"
3. After that I have given the command `sudo mount -t vboxsf UbuntuShared /media/UbuntuShared`

I am getting the following error

```
[sudo] password for sudhakar: 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on UbuntuShared,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

sudhakar@sudhakar-VirtualBox:~$ dmesg | tail
[   27.609673] intel8x0: measured clock 125841 rejected
[   27.968145] intel8x0_measure_ac97_clock: measured 55818 usecs (7680 samples)
[   27.968145] intel8x0: measured clock 137590 rejected
[   27.968145] intel8x0: clocking to 48000
[   29.853093] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (913) terminated with status 1
[   30.848121] init: plymouth-splash main process (996) terminated with status 1
[   33.188179] vboxsf: Successfully loaded version 4.3.10 (interface 0x00010004)
[   34.944719] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1217) terminated with status 1
[  753.448878] hrtimer: interrupt took 19272977 ns
[ 1102.388151] sf_read_super_aux err=-22
```

Answer (score 9):

Apparently there is a bad symlink. I had the exact same problem and this fixed it. Good luck.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions
```

Found solution here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=60921

Comment: i dont see anything under /opt/