# Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?

Tags: mount, nfs

When mounting an NFS directory by doing:

```
sudo mount 192.168.1.5:/home/shared /mnt/common
```

I get the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 192.168.1.5:/home/shared, missing codepage or helper program, or other error (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)  
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.
```

The kernel is up to date.

The question was already asked (for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/458286/229568) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/372445/229568)), but are either [not answered](https://askubuntu.com/q/523178/229568) or the answers are not helpful in my case.

What is wrong?

Comment: I met this issue before, just install an extended tool
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils

Comment: user413408's fix didn't help me.

Comment: Similar issues can be solved on CentOS clients by `sudo yum install nfs-utils`.

Comment: had the same error, because the drive had to be partitioned first! May sound obvious, but just putting it out there to start there.

Comment: If the error relates to setting up an sshfs mount, the `sshfs` package may be missing (fix with `sudo apt install sshfs` or `sudo yum install sshfs` etc)

Answer (score 386, accepted):

The error message mentions:

> (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount. helper program)

This is relevant given that you are trying to mount NFS. The `/sbin/mount.nfs` helper program is provided by [`nfs-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mount.nfs&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any). You can install it with:

```
sudo apt install nfs-common
```

On the other hand, if you are trying to mount CIFS, the helper program is provided by [`cifs-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/cifs-utils). You can install it with:

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

Comment: Meaning: `apt-get install nfs-common`, if `/sbin/mount.nfs` is not already there.

Comment: This did it for me: "sudo apt-get install cifs-utils".

Comment: On ubuntu 14 "/sbin/mount.nfs" is already present but still unable to mount with the same error mentioned.
After installing "nfs-common", I was able to mount without any issues.

Comment: your package might be nfs-utils

Comment: It is worth to note, make sure you are not getting "/sbin/mount.nfs" mixed up with "/sbin/mount.ntfs". The latter is a different file system, specifically coming out of the microsoft world. nfs and ntfs are two different file systems and are not compatible

Answer (score 73):

Make sure `mount.cifs` is listed into `/sbin`:

```
ls -l /sbin/mount.cifs
```

Check to see if package `cifs-utils` is installed:

```
dpkg -l cifs-utils
```

If it isn't, install the cifs libraries with

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Comment: cifs can be installed via the cifs-utils package.

Comment: I had to reinstall cifs-utils on my system for some reason, it said it was installed, but the file at /sbin/mount.cifs was missing.

Comment: This combined with `sudo mount -t cifs //SERVER/FOLDER /media/FOLDER -o username=USER,domain=DOMAIN` command enables you to mount file shares on Windows active directory domains.

Comment: [`cifs-utils`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/cifs-utils) provides tools for working with samba shares (SMB/CIFS protocols), but OP needed to mount NFS shares, and needs to install [`nfs-common`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/nfs-common) package instead, as suggested [in this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/525246/125726). NFS is different from SMB/CIFS!

Comment: YES READ OP. **"When mounting an NFS directory"** As mentioned: you need nfs-common normally installed. Why are all these other answers upvoted? Answered above. This does hold true for CIFS mounting. But wasn't the question.

Answer (score 24):

It appears that `nfs-common` package should be installed in order to be able to mount NFS directories.

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

When it's not, the mounting of an NFS directory results in the error I've got.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by installing virtualbox.
Do

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

It installs the `mount.vboxsf`

Comment: What makes you think the OP is running a virtualbox guest ?

Comment: I find this answer alright  if he saw the same error when trying to connect from a Virtualbox guest, and he installed the `virtualbox-guest-utils` to solve the problem. It does not answer the OP question but answers somebody else facing the problem with virtualbox guest.

Comment: Although this may not answer OP's question, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mount -t nfs 192.168.1.5:/home/shared /mnt/common
```

Comment: Yes, but also first you need to be sure you already installed nfs-common. Otherwise this wont work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I tried the nfs-common package install without any success.

I was able to resolve the same issue you had by:

1. Going to the Linux "disks" application.
2. Clicking the USB drive I was trying to mount in the devices section (window left).
3. Clicking more actions under the Volumes filesystem partition section (two little gears right of the minus/plus signs).
4. Clicking edit mount options (top of the mount options window).
5. Clicking to TURN ON Automatic Mount Options.
6. Then clicking the mount button (+ sign under volumes) -- this should change to a square.

This mounted my USB drive and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me on ubuntu 22.04:
Gparted guided as below:
[image]

After installing the ntfs-3g it works fine:

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```