# Not able to mount?

Tags: fstab, nfs

I am trying to install a software from remote server

```
sudo mount -t cifs //10.16.4.96/share /opt/matlab8.4 -o guest
```

It gives me error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //10.16.4.96/share,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

I installted nfs-common as mentioned in this answer: [Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525243/why-do-i-get-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-error)

Still facing the same problem. What I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nfs-common` is for NFS mounts. For CIFS mounts, you need `mount.cifs`, which is [provided by](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mount.cifs&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) `cifs-utils`.