# external USB drive no write access

Tags: mount, usb-drive, format, 19.04

I downloadet Ubuntu and copied to my USB pen with Windows 10.

And after reboot, I installed Ubuntu on the same Laptop. After some software installation Ubuntu asked me first to update to version 18.10, I confirmed and updatet. Round 3days later Ubuntu asked me again to update to Version 19.04., I also confirmed.

But now,I dont have any write access to my USB pen.I cant delete the files or I cant format the pen. But copy from the pen to Ubuntu is working without issues.

I read a lot of ways to fix it on the internet, but nothing is working.

When I try to format I get the error:

```
Error wiping device: Failed to open the device '/dev/sda2' (udsiks-error-quark, 0)
```

When I try to format with **gnome-disks**, I cant because formatting is grey and I cant click on it.

When I try to open with gparted I have the same read-only error

```
Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
```

and in the systemlog:

```
/var/log/syslog
    May 27 23:11:29 Lenovo-B51-80 udisksd[717]: Cleaning up mount point /media/sebastian/SanDisk (device 8:18 is not mounted)
    May 27 23:11:29 Lenovo-B51-80 ntfs-3g[10126]: Unmounting /dev/sdb2 (SanDisk)
    May 27 23:11:29 Lenovo-B51-80 systemd[1434]: media-sebastian-SanDisk.mount: Succeeded.
    May 27 23:11:29 Lenovo-B51-80 systemd[1]: media-sebastian-SanDisk.mount: Succeeded.
    May 27 23:11:29 Lenovo-B51-80 systemd[1]: Stopping Clean the /media/sebastian/SanDisk mount point...
    May 27 23:11:29 Lenovo-B51-80 systemd[1]: clean-mount-point@media-sebastian-SanDisk.service: Succeeded.
    May 27 23:11:29 Lenovo-B51-80 systemd[1]: Stopped Clean the /media/sebastian/SanDisk mount point.
    May 27 23:11:29 Lenovo-B51-80 udisksd[717]: Unmounted /dev/sdb2 on behalf of uid 1000
```

and state of

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

What can I do to fix the USB pen?

Comment: I suggest you try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1100967/880592

Comment: Then it's very likely your USB stick is defective.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, but the same issue:

```
dus 12.3.2 
Live drive, that is booted from: /dev/sda
cands=1
sdb
SanDisk_Ultra_Fit
114,6G
usb
USB or memory card
p_target: target=/dev/sdb
Restore  /dev/sdb 
to an MSDOS partition table and a
partition with a FAT32 file system
MODEL     NAME   FSTYPE LABEL     SIZE
Ultra_Fit sdb                   114,6G
          ├─sdb1 vfat             512M
          └─sdb2 ntfs   SanDisk 114,1G
restore
/dev/sdb
-----
Trying to unmount partitions if mounted on the target device
umount: /dev/sdb: not mounted.
umount: /dev/sdb1: not mounted.
umount: /dev/sdb2: not mounted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gpt_zap: done
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': Read-only file system
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't write to /dev/sdb, because it is opened read-only.
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Error: You requested a partition from 1049kB to 123GB (sectors 2048..240254975).
The closest location we can manage is 1048kB to 1048kB (sectors 2047..2047).
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't write to /dev/sdb, because it is opened read-only.
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdb1: Read-only file system
 Failed :-( 
  mk_msdos: could not create MSDOS partition table and FAT file system 
Wait 5 seconds and a little more ...
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Model: SanDisk Ultra Fit (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 123GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   123GB  122GB  ntfs                               msftdata


MODEL     NAME   FSTYPE LABEL
Ultra_Fit sdb           
          ├─sdb1 vfat   
          └─sdb2 ntfs   SanDisk
p_clean:
clean if necessary and quit
```