# How to repair broken flash-device?

Tags: flash, dd, fdisk

May be it was wrong decision, but I had no opportunity to make it in another way. I'd tried to burn image of **Windows** by means of **dd** on Ubuntu. I used it as usually, but once it'd gotten stuck on some moment and I just unplugged my USB-flesh and tried to plug in once again. **fdisk** couldn't detect `/dev/sdb` device, however, I was able to watch files on USB-flash. I didn't pay attention, but after I perceived this image is wrong. I wanted to clean up my USB-flash devise, but now I cannot make something. When I try

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
```

I get

```
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found
```

`dmesg, lsusb` detect my device. `lsblk` sees nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover USB flash drive functionality after having used dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044056/how-to-recover-usb-flash-drive-functionality-after-having-used-dd)

Comment: Try with gparted

Comment: If you can't even see the device name `/dev/XdY` (where `X` and `Y` are the identifiers of the USB stick) then it's utterly broken and needs to be replaced.