# How to recovery a USB when I can't format it with GParted or Disk

Tags: partitioning, usb, 20.04, disk, format

I have made a Format using Disk in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I copy some files in the directory a ISO file (without making a Booteable USB), eject the USB and then I plug in again and it didn't work ... I don't know what was the problem because I wait before every files was saved in the memory and now I can't access or format with Disk. The command sudo `fdisk -l` don't show also the USB. The only part where I can see the USB is app from Ubuntu `Disk`, but I can't do anything (Attach some Screenshots).

[Disk Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBSjW.png)

[Options unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iosn2.png)

I have tried several solutions to fix the USB but any works. [The steps here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044056/how-to-recover-usb-flash-drive-functionality-after-having-used-dd) don't work because I received the next error:

```bsh
jairom:~$ sudo parted -a none /dev/sdb mkpart primary fat32 0 32768
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

Update: 
Output of `sudo mount -l`

```bsh
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=6057000k,nr_inodes=1514250,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1217028k,mode=755)
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=15042)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_128.snap on /snap/skype/128 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_433.snap on /snap/snap-store/433 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_1397.snap on /snap/vlc/1397 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gimp_252.snap on /snap/gimp/252 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/postman_107.snap on /snap/postman/107 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/code_32.snap on /snap/code/32 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/audacity_648.snap on /snap/audacity/648 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/drawio_29.snap on /snap/drawio/29 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-34-1804_33.snap on /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kdenlive_24.snap on /snap/kdenlive/24 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_9066.snap on /snap/core/9066 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_123.snap on /snap/skype/123 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/intellij-idea-community_216.snap on /snap/intellij-idea-community/216 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1506.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/octave_29.snap on /snap/octave/29 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/postman_108.snap on /snap/postman/108 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/code_33.snap on /snap/code/33 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/libreoffice_177.snap on /snap/libreoffice/177 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_116.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1754.snap on /snap/core18/1754 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_7264.snap on /snap/snapd/7264 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18_4.snap on /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1705.snap on /snap/core18/1705 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/drawio_28.snap on /snap/drawio/28 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_1620.snap on /snap/vlc/1620 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/intellij-idea-community_227.snap on /snap/intellij-idea-community/227 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk2-common-themes_9.snap on /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-34-1804_27.snap on /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/27 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_95.snap on /snap/canonical-livepatch/95 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sda4 on /media/jairom/data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,x-gvfs-show) [data]
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1217028k,mode=755)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/canonical-livepatch.mnt type nsfs (rw)
vmware-vmblock on /run/vmblock-fuse type fuse.vmware-vmblock (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1217024k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/fuse on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt type nsfs (rw)
```

There is any solution? I really don't understand what was the problem, it seems my computer don't reject well the USBs, but I have never had this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with GParted. Does it pop up there? 
Mind that you have to select the drive in the top right corner. The default drive is your hard drive.

Comment: No, I can't see the USB in Gparted, it doesn't appear.

Comment: have tried mounting it manually?

Comment: @NelsonVanegasA. yeah I have tried, I can see the device, I know it is the `/dev/sdb` but the command shows `can't find in /etc/fstab.`