# wipe usb drive - read only error

Tags: usb, usb-drive, secure-erase

I have an usb drive of 8gb and I tried to wipe it in all the way

dd mkusb mkfs gparted utility disk

windows diskpart

mac utility disk diskutil erase

anytime i get "read only permission denied". obviusly i tried to set permission on it but nothing changed

is there anyone with an idea or a great working suggestion ?

thanks

Comment: Is the USB drive a drive that has a write-protection switch on it, or no?  If the answer is no, then I would surmise the USB drive is broken and nonfunctional, because it likely can't be properly read/written to and is causing errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover USB flash drive functionality after having used dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044056/how-to-recover-usb-flash-drive-functionality-after-having-used-dd)

Comment: sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel msdos
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb
has been opened read-only.
Warning: Partition(s) on /dev/sdb are being used.
Ignore/Cancel? I                                                          
Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sdb will be destroyed and all data on
this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?
Yes/No? Y                                                                 
Error: Can't write to /dev/sdb, because it is opened read-only.
Ignore/Cancel? I

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ThomasWard -- with the cost of thumb drives today, it's not worth spending much time on it.  If there was sensitive data on the drive, you might want to get a hammer or similar and *physically* destroy the drive (including the Flash RAM package on the circuit board inside) to ensure it can't be read, as well as not being able to be written, but otherwise, it's not worth your time to try to deal with it.

Comment: yes sure maybe is waste time, but i can learn something ..anyway it happend while i was writing a big iso to the usb with "iso to usb" windows software, and in that while system crash and i removed the drive, after that moment i had the error