# What should I do ? After, Removing my drive in between formating.Can you please suggest me a website

Tags: usb-drive, google, data-corruption, disk-formatting

How do I  format it to make it like a regular pendrive.?
I was recently trying to boot the Chrome OS Flex in my pendrive in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system, using google guide from this website.

[Google support for installation](https://support.google.com/chromeosflex/answer/11541904?hl=en&ref_topic=11551271)

When I use dd command with it,

`sudo dd if=chrome_os.bin of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress` 
After some time it just stopped showing anything. I left it several hours but nothing. I tried to eject, but it also did nothing. So, I pull it out immediately. After this incident, it stops working. I tried to format it in every way I read on internet. I even used windows disk format but it also did nothing. I am so confused.
I have a Toshiba 64 gb.
I think that my pendrive has corrupted.
Sorry for bad English.
This is the screenshot of disks app.
[image]

It goes on forever. And it gives a popup after 3-4 hours.Since I cannot stay for that long again. \

This is the log file of using rufus

[image]

This is what mkusb doing ,it stucks here.

[image]

@Karel I did all the steps from the question you linked and they did nothing to it.

This screen stucks when I make partion using AOMEI Partition Assistant
[image]

**

> In simple words, I have pluged out my pendrive in between dd command
> and now, it is formating, writable,readable,etc.So,what should I do to
> fix it?

***@Sudodus alright I want to want to know from where should I read all these eisks before dealing with commands.
Please suggest me a website***

Comment: I’m afraid there’s literally nothing to go on in terms of trying to answer your question. Have a look in the help centre https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask  … give us some details to work on we don’t know anything about your hardware, how  you used dd, etc.

Comment: Also - the title of your question is meaningless - that’s what people will see when choosing whether you open your question and try to help.

Comment: Is that right now

Comment: Sorry for that.

Comment: I am trying to format the pendrive and it didn't format.It crashes the app with which I used

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover USB flash drive functionality after having used dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044056/how-to-recover-usb-flash-drive-functionality-after-having-used-dd)

Comment: I tried it using disks app, using disk management,  using aomei partition, using terminal , using mkusb etc.

Comment: Everything you tried didn't work,so try my method which is specific to recovering USB flash drive functionality after running `dd` on the USB flash drive.

Comment: I am trying to use it.

Comment: should I share a screenshot of it.

Comment: It's all done from the terminal command line, so you don't need to post a screenshot because copy/pasting the plain text from the terminal is better.

Comment: not of that , should i share screenshot when i am using disks app

Comment: Optionally it's OK to post a link to that screenshot.

Comment: In Disks are you choosing "Format" in the hamburger menu (the three dots on the top right) or are you trying to add a partition with the `+` button? You should be trying to Format. The Disks screenshot shows us that the hardware is recognized as a storage device, so if the format fails or hangs and never completes then the likelihood is high that the hardware has died.

Comment: @Nmath `dd` does weird things to some models of USB flash drives. I tried about 20 different methods over the course of more than a year before I discovered a method of restoring functionality to a USB flash drive after running `dd` that actually worked.

Comment: No, if i use another pc it also takes so much time.And last day I don't know how am I able to Format the disk.And Now I am trying to create a partition and it does the same.

Comment: @Feystray, You have really tried hard with this USB pendrive. I'm afraid that it failed during the cloning operation with `dd`. Pendrives are mass produced, and there are lots of evidence of sudden failures. It can happen during any write operation (I would not blame `dd`). You may find 'a few more tips' at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), but I think you have done enough to conclude that your pendrive is damaged beyond repair.

Comment: That is sad,I have only one 64 GB pendrive left and stays for almost 2 years of use.But, using dd is very risky to it.Since , I am new to commands and all that because I am a windows user for atleast 6 years and learn almost everything using gui.

Comment: @Feystray, I agree that `dd` is risky when cloning drives, but it is mainly because it does what you tell it to do without any question. So if you tell it to overwrite the family pictures, it does so without hesitating. But if you wrap a security overcoat around it, as I do with mkusb, the risk is reduced a lot. Generally, it is a good idea to use tools with a final checkpoint, where you can double-check, that you have chosen the correct target for operations directly onto the drive or its partition table.

Comment: I have never destroyed any USB pendrive with `dd` via mkusb. When a pendrive is getting 'tired', when the write speed is reduced to less than half of the original one, it is a good idea to wipe the whole device, overwrite it with zeros. It will not only restore the write speed to almost the original one, but it will also reduce the risk of 'gridlock', a failure mode, where the drive hardware becomes read-only. See also [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297) and links from it.

Comment: Alright , I will throw it in dustbin

Comment: Thanks for help