# How to mount .img file created from ddrescue from failing hard drive

Tags: mount, filesystem, ddrescue

I've been following this tutorial which got me far enough to create an image file of my failing disc.

https://www.technibble.com/guide-using-ddrescue-recover-data/

I'm following step 3a, but I am greeted with an error that says:
"wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop8"

I followed the directions found at the following link to no avail:
[Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525243/why-do-i-get-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-error)

I installed nfs-common, but it didn't help.

I then tried booting into windows and simply mounting the image through windows, and I'm getting a "The disc image is corrupted" error.

My guess is that I don't know what type of file system the disc image is. (It's off a friends computer, and all I know is that is was a Linux system) Maybe if I knew the file system type I could use this command with the proper trigger and it'd work?

```
sudo mount -t fstype -o loop,ro partition.img mountpoint
```

So, I guess my question is this. How can I look at the type of filesystem that the .img file is? Or, even better how can I mount this .img file so I can browse the files that I was able to recover (ddrescue reported 49% recovered) and just copy the ones that survived to another drive?

For what it's worth, I am only running Ubuntu on a Live USB, and therefore if I boot into Ubuntu again to do this, I'll have to reinstall any necessary programs etc. So, if you can help, the more you can spell out to me, the better! I'm an Ubuntu newb, so don't really know what I'm doing at all!

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track. To discover the `fstype` just do a `blkid partition.img` and look at the TYPE. It should be the parameter listed last.

for instance:

> ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ blkid /media/ubuntu/media/restore/20190915-ddrescue.img
>
> /media/ubuntu/media/restore/20190915-ddrescue.img: UUID="a2d5575a-98d3-415d-b569-8f9138f08eb4" UUID_SUB="2f192535-a318-478e-bd16-d7d8093ec1ed" TYPE="btrfs"