# problem mounting new disk partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, ext4, sd-card

I'm trying to install Arch Linux for a Raspberry Pi 2 according to their instructions on http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2 on a brand new 64G micro-SD card. I'm doing so using an Oracle VM Virtual Box with Ubuntu v14.04 LTS within a Windows 7 environment. I'm somewhat inexperienced with Ubuntu and Linux in general. Also, SD card and the reader that I'm writing to were VERY cheap from China via ebay, so I'm suspicious of a problem with the SD card at this point.

Anyway, after formatting the disk and creating partitions using fdisk seemingly without incident, I get to step 4 in the Arch instructions, which says to do the following:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX2
mkdir root
mount /dev/sdX2 root
```

the result I get is:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, 
missing codepage or helper program, or other error 
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try 
dmesg | tail or so
```

`dmesg | tail` gives the following:

```
[ 6231.419388]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[ 6275.385637] JBD2: no valid journal superblock found
[ 6275.385644] EXT4-fs (sdb2): error loading journal
```

I found a few other questions with similar problems, such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525243/why-do-i-get-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-error), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458286/getting-an-error-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-on-ubuntushared), and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372445/fat-fs-sdc1-io-charset-iso8859-1-not-found-error-while-mounting-fat-drives) but none of them have solved my problem.

What is going on?

Comment: mount typically requires the `--types` option , also known as `-t` . Try this  `mount  -t ext4 /dev/sdb2 root`. Perhaps partitioning went wrong somewhere. Try reformating the card and starting from scratch.  If you don't mind me asking, why would you like to install Arch ? ( Not taking any distro sides here, just offering a possibility of trying other OSs , such as Raspbian or Mate , for considerations ). Arch installations can be tricky and certainly not for newcomers to the linux world

Comment: I've used arch before. I actually have more arch experience than any other Linux distro. I think it's well suited for embedded applications where I want the most stripped down OS possible.

Answer (score 1):

you have problems with your mount command please use this

mount -t ext4 /dev/sdX2 /root

If you have any further questions please do not hesitate to ask me.

Comment: I actually just found a solution elsewhere. I don't have the exact command I used in front of me anymore, but It supposedly made the ext4 filesystem without journals.

Comment: @kjgregory may I suggest posting an answer so that future users may find your solution helpful ?  Thanks

Comment: This is the command that got me past the error message: `mke2fs -t ext4 -O ^has_journal /dev/sdb2`. My Raspberry Pi doesn't seem to boot up yet, so it seems there is still a problem with my setup.